# mat-selection-list returns empty list when options are selected programmatically and not touched anything

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have `mat-selection-list` in my project that shows list of roles in the project and existing roles of the group are selected programmatically. So far everything works as expected

```
<div *ngIf="group!==undefined" class="col-12" style="margin-top: 30px">
    <h4>Group Roles</h4>
    <mat-selection-list [compareWith]="roleCompareFn" [formControl]="rolesControl" >
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let role of allRoles" [selected]="doesGroupHasThisRole(role)" [value]="role" checkboxPosition="before" style="font-size: 14px">
            {{role.name}}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="getSelectedRoles()">Submit</button>
</div>

<h2>Selected Roles:</h2>
<div *ngFor="let role of selectedRoles" >
  {{role.name}}
</div>
```

When click on submit and try to get list of selected roles I get **empty list**. But when I select/change anything, I get all the selected roles. Sample of this created in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tctdo3?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.html) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jadda, if you're manage a multiple select forget use [selected] in the options. a multiple select need a control that store an array. You can store an array of roles (then use [compareWith]) or an array if numbers, the use [value]="roles.id"

See how simple is (see that we use [value]="role.id"

```
<mat-selection-list [formControl]="rolesControl" >
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let role of allRoles" [value]="role.id">
        {{role.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

And you can use, e.g.

rolesControl = new FormControl([1,3]);
//or
this.rolesControl.setValue([2,4])

If you want store an array of roles, you need

```
<mat-selection-list [formControl]="rolesControl" >
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let role of allRoles" [value]="role">
        {{role.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

And, when defined the value of the control

```
 rolesControl = new FormControl([
      {id:2,name:"ROLE_SELLER"},
      {id:4,name:"ROLE_BUYER"}]);

 //or 
 this.rolesControl.setValue([
      {id:2,name:"ROLE_SELLER"},
      {id:4,name:"ROLE_BUYER"}]);
```

NOTE: Some times, It's interesting write in the .html, only for check:

```
<pre>
{{rolesControl?.value|json}}
</pre>
```

NOTE2: In your code you has the same "id" for differents roles

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, it fixed my issue. May I know why `[selected]` didn't work? And also I fixed the ids of roles

Comment: Jadda, if you use [selected] and formControlName, you're saying to Angular that make the "same thing" twices. Should  work, but it's not the way. I know that in the component examples in Material don't use FormControl or [(ngModel)] this is because Material can be used also outside Angular